# Technical term for a single test case result

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

What is the technical term for the result associated with the single execution of a single test case. For example, I have a results directory in which I save each of my test cases: Test 123, Test 456 etc. Subsequently, each test case directory contains a set of folders with the current date and time, where I save the result and logs for a single execution of a test case: 2011-10-12 12,25,219200000, 2011-10-11 19,12,121900000.

So "Test 123" is a "Test Case Results Folder". But what is "2011-10-12 12,25,219200000"? Is it a "Single Test Case Execution Result Folder", "Test Case Instance Result Folder" or something better?

Any suggestions of a good term?

Thanks,

Barry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd name it "Test Case Result" or "Test Case Output" (without folder) as those folders stand for one actual result in a whole.